Save Multiple entities having one to many mapping cause dynamic db calls
Let two entities: School (id, name) and Student (id, name, SchoolId). There is one to many mapping from student to school. For Saving list of students in Spring boot:
public void saveStudents(List<Student> studentList, School school){
        for(Student student: studentList){
               student.setSchool(school);
        }
        studentRepositor.saveAll(studentList)
}

For a list of 1000 students, this saveAll() causes 1000 db calls, which are expensive. How to do this efficiently?
I have tried batch insertion using spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true ,   noted here.
But this causes higher latency, also if list size increases, batch call and latency time increases too.
How can I do this efficiently?
Actually, I have to copy certain students to students table with different id, and corresponding schools in schools table. I can do this by native query, but that would violate Database Agnostic feature. Can anyone help me in this regard?
The two entities :
@Entity
@Table(name = "school")
public class School extends BaseEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 128)
  private String id;

  @DiffIgnore
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "school", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<Student> students;
  }

and student :
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student extends BaseEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 128)
  private String id;
  
  @ShallowReference
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinColumn(name = "school_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
  private School school;
}


How do you plan to make 1000 inserts without 1000 inserts?

I don't get it, isn't the mapping 1 to 1, not 1 to many?

How long time does it takes? ANd do you need order_inserts? It's seems to be only for identity which you don't seem to have?

Show us your Entities code and how they are annotated.

@K.Nicholas , We can use batch insertion to insert 1000 entries. However, in my case, I have to copy 1000 entries from existing table , set the column : "amount" to zero , then enter as new entry in the similar table .

@siggemannen this is one to many mapping, I have tried order_inserts , this batch insertion cause 417 milliseconds for 200 entries, vs trivial 200 db call cause 117 milliseconds. Batch insertion has performance issue .

If performance is the main concern, I would recommend playing a bit with the following properties for spring jpa Hibernate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=250. # or whatever you would like
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true # you already have this

saveAll() with batching would still be way more efficient then save(), one reason being that only a single Transaction would be created for the batch.
